# Unable to rescale images for figures

Tags: graphics

I am writing a research paper for a word matching game. However, when I try to rescale the images for my paper the sizing does not change. The code below generates the figures:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4, clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{figure/fig_1.PNG}
  \caption{Word Match Generator Before Dragging Boxes}
  \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4, clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{figure/Figure2.png}
  \caption{Word Match After Dragging Boxes}
  \label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.2, clip,width=0.9\linewidth]{figure/congratulations_button.PNG}
  \caption{Congratulations Dialog Box}
  \label{fig:fig3}
\end{figure}
```

Expected:
A set of figures are generated such that any modification to `scale=0.2` should change the figure size.

Actual:
The figures remain the same despite any change:
[image]

Any help understanding how to fix this issue would be helpful.

Comment: You are telling `includegraphics` to scale your figure to 90% of the line width... Use scale OR width

Comment: First you scale image to 0.2 natural size and than this scale to `0.9\linewidth`.  The same result you will get if you use scale only to `0.9\linewidth`. So, it is not clear, what is goal of your scaling ...

Comment: Now if you want to scale the image, test if it is less than \linewidth and only then shrink it further, you can use a savebox.  `\sbox0{\incudegraphics[scale=0.2]{...}}` `\ifdim\wd0>\linewidth \resizebox{\linewidth}{\box0} \else \centering\box0 \fi`